# I want to remove the required for column outlet_serve_method, I want to make it nullable or can be left empty

Tags: php, laravel

I want to remove the required for column outlet_serve_method, I want to make it nullable or can be left empty. I tried to change into `'outlet_serve_methods' => 'nullable`', but still the same. In the form I cannot leave it empty in that column... whyyyyyyyy???

So below is my controller function

```
 public function editOutletPost(Request $request, $outletId)
    {     
        $isDraft = $request->boolean('is_draft');

        // Configure the rules for add outlet function
        $rules = [
            'outlet_name' => 'required',
            'outlet_email' => ['required', 'email', Rule::unique('outlets', 'email')->ignore($outletId)],
            'outlet_contact_no' => 'required',
            'outlet_address' => 'required',
            'outlet_state' => 'required',
            'outlet_postcode' => 'required|min:5',
            /*'outlet_latitude' => 'required',
            'outlet_longitude' => 'required',*/
            'outlet_image' => 'sometimes',
            'outlet_menus' => 'required',
            'outlet_combos' => 'required',
            'outlet_drinks' => 'required',
            'outlet_side_dishes' => 'required',
            'outlet_serve_methods' => 'nullable',
            'outlet_delivery_option' => [
                Rule::requiredIf(in_array(2, $request->outlet_serve_methods ?? []))
            ],
            'outlet_delivery_range_coverage' => [
                Rule::requiredIf(in_array(2, $request->outlet_serve_methods ?? []))
            ],
        ];

        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);

        // If validation fails...
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json([
                'status' => false,
                'error' => $validator->errors()
            ]);
        }

        // --Store outlet image function.
        if (!is_null($request->outlet_image)) {
            $imageName = Str::of(Str::random(30)) . '.' . $request->file('outlet_image')->extension();
            $imageFullPath = $this->outletUploadPath . $imageName;
            Storage::put($imageFullPath, file_get_contents($request->file('outlet_image')));
        }

        // --Check for available for lalamove delivery or not.
        $lalamoveDelivery = true;
        if (!in_array('1', $request->outlet_delivery_option)) {
            $lalamoveDelivery = false;
        }

        // --Check for available for inhouse delivery or not.
        $inHouseDelivery = true;
        if (!in_array('2', $request->outlet_delivery_option)) {
            $inHouseDelivery = false;
        }

        try {
            DB::beginTransaction();

            // --Check whether selected menu, combos, side dishes, drinks is all or specific.
            $checkMenus = false;
            if (in_array('all', $request->outlet_menus)) {
                $checkMenus = true;
            }
            $checkCombos = false;
            if (in_array('all', $request->outlet_combos)) {
                $checkCombos = true;
            }
            $checkSideDishes = false;
            if (in_array('all', $request->outlet_side_dishes)) {
                $checkSideDishes = true;
            }
            $checkDrinks = false;
            if (in_array('all', $request->outlet_drinks)) {
                $checkDrinks = true;
            }

            // --Get available serve methods.
            $dinein = $delivery = $pickup = $reservation = false;
            if (in_array(1, $request->outlet_serve_methods)) {
                $dinein = true;
            }
            if (in_array(2, $request->outlet_serve_methods)) {
                $delivery = true;
            }
            if (in_array(3, $request->outlet_serve_methods)) {
                $pickup = true;
            }
            if (in_array(4, $request->outlet_serve_methods)) {
                $reservation = true;
            }


            //-----remove these when map fixed-----
            if(empty($request->outlet_latitude)){
                $request->outlet_latitude = "0";
            }
            if(empty($request->outlet_longitude)){
                $request->outlet_longitude = "0";
            }
            //-----remove these when map fixed-----

            // Create new outlet data
            $editOutletObj = Outlet::find($outletId);

            $editOutletObj->name = $request->outlet_name;
            $editOutletObj->email = $request->outlet_email;
            $editOutletObj->address = $request->outlet_address;
            $editOutletObj->postcode = $request->outlet_postcode;
            $editOutletObj->state_id = $request->outlet_state;
            $editOutletObj->latitude = $request->outlet_latitude;
            $editOutletObj->longitude = $request->outlet_longitude;
            $editOutletObj->contact_no = $request->outlet_contact_no;

            if (!is_null($request->outlet_image)) {
                $editOutletObj->image = $imageName;
            }

            $editOutletObj->applicable_all_menu = $checkMenus;
            $editOutletObj->applicable_all_combo = $checkCombos;
            $editOutletObj->applicable_all_side_dish = $checkSideDishes;
            $editOutletObj->applicable_all_drink = $checkDrinks;
            $editOutletObj->dinein = $dinein;
            $editOutletObj->delivery = $delivery;
            $editOutletObj->pickup = $pickup;
            $editOutletObj->reservation = $reservation;
            $editOutletObj->reservation_slots_per_hour = $request->outlet_reservation_slot_per_hour;
            $editOutletObj->reservation_slots_per_hour_count = $request->outlet_reservation_slot_per_hour;
            $editOutletObj->order_slots_per_hour = $request->outlet_order_slot_per_hour;
            $editOutletObj->order_slots_per_hour_count = $request->outlet_order_slot_per_hour;
            $editOutletObj->pizza_make_per_hour = $request->outlet_available_pizza_per_hour;
            $editOutletObj->pizza_make_per_hour_count = $request->outlet_available_pizza_per_hour;
            $editOutletObj->event_reservation_slot_per_hour = $request->event_reservation_slot_per_hour;
            $editOutletObj->lalamove_delivery = $lalamoveDelivery;
            $editOutletObj->in_house_delivery = $inHouseDelivery;
            $editOutletObj->delivery_range_coverage = $request->outlet_delivery_range_coverage;
            $editOutletObj->sst = $request->boolean('outlet_apply_sst');
            $editOutletObj->service_tax = $request->boolean('outlet_apply_service_tax');
            //$editOutletObj->status = $isDraft ? false : true;
            $editOutletObj->save();
            
            // --Remove all previous record.
            OutletOperationHour::where('outlet_id', $outletId)->delete();
            
            $this->operation_hour = [];
            $day_list = ['monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday', 'sunday'];
            foreach($day_list as $days){
                $count = 0;
                switch($days) {
                    case "monday":
                        $count = count($request->outlet_start_monday);
                        $this->operationHourMerge($days, $count, $request->outlet_start_monday, $request->outlet_end_monday, $request->boolean('outlet_monday_status'));
                    break;
                    case "tuesday":
                        $count = count($request->outlet_start_tuesday);
                        $this->operationHourMerge($days, $count, $request->outlet_start_tuesday, $request->outlet_end_tuesday, $request->boolean('outlet_tuesday_status'));
                    break;
                    case "wednesday":
                        $count = count($request->outlet_start_wednesday);
                        $this->operationHourMerge($days, $count, $request->outlet_start_wednesday, $request->outlet_end_wednesday, $request->boolean('outlet_wednesday_status'));
                    break;
                    case "thursday":
                        $count = count($request->outlet_start_thursday);
                        $this->operationHourMerge($days, $count, $request->outlet_start_thursday, $request->outlet_end_thursday, $request->boolean('outlet_thursday_status'));
                    break;
                    case "friday":
                        $count = count($request->outlet_start_friday);
                        $this->operationHourMerge($days, $count, $request->outlet_start_friday, $request->outlet_end_friday, $request->boolean('outlet_friday_status'));
                    break;
                    case "saturday":
                        $count = count($request->outlet_start_saturday);
                        $this->operationHourMerge($days, $count, $request->outlet_start_saturday, $request->outlet_end_saturday, $request->boolean('outlet_saturday_status'));
                    break;
                    case "sunday":
                        $count = count($request->outlet_start_sunday);
                        $this->operationHourMerge($days, $count, $request->outlet_start_sunday, $request->outlet_end_sunday, $request->boolean('outlet_sunday_status'));
                    break;
                    default:
                        return; 
                }    
            }
            
            // --Insert operation hours.
            $editOutletObj->operation_hour()->createMany($this->operation_hour);

            // --Insert menus, combos, side_dishes, drinks to pivot table.
            if ($checkMenus == false) {
                $editOutletObj->menus()->sync($request->outlet_menus);
            }

            if ($checkCombos == false) {
                $editOutletObj->combos()->sync($request->outlet_combos);
            }

            if ($checkSideDishes == false) {
                $editOutletObj->side_dishes()->sync($request->outlet_side_dishes);
            }

            if ($checkDrinks == false) {
                $editOutletObj->drinks()->sync($request->outlet_drinks);
            }

            if ($isDraft) {
                foreach ($editOutletObj->tokens as $token) {
                    // Revoke past token.
                    $token->revoke();
                }
            }

            DB::commit();

            return response()->json([
                'status' => true
            ]);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            DB::rollback();
            return $e->getMessage();
            return response()->json([
                'status' => false,
                'error' => 'Something went wrong, Please try again later or contact the administator.'
            ]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are still using it everywhere you do `$request->outlet_serve_methods`, so your code is still depending on that field.

Comment: You say "In the form I cannot leave it empty in that column", but this isn't enough information for us to help you. What happens when you try to do this? What error or problem do you experience?